# RSASSA-PSS signed in java verified with c#

Tags: java, c#, cryptography

I have a signature that was issued by a java service like this:

```
File file = new File("<path-to-private-key>");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fileInputStream.read(bytes);
String key = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
key = key
        .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .replace("\r\n", "")
        .replace("\n", "")
        .replace(" ", "");

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key));
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("RSASSA-PSS");
signer.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-512", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA512, 64, 1));
signer.initSign(privateKey);
signer.update(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] byteArraySignature = signer.sign();
signature = encoder.encodeToString(message);
```

And then I have a .net service that verifies it like this:

```
var fileStream = File.OpenText("<path-to-public-key>");
var pemReader = new PemReader(fileStream);
var publicKey = ((Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)pemReader.ReadObject()).GetPublicKey();
var signer = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha512Digest(), 64);
signer.Init(false, (RsaKeyParameters)publicKey);
var bytes = UTF8.GetBytes(message);
signer.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
var isvalid = signer.VerifySignature(Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
```

the problem is that .net service says the signature is invalid. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I also tried this:

```
var publicKey = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
var isValid = publicKey.VerifyData(UTF8.GetBytes(message), Convert.FromBase64String(signature), HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
```

Is there any configuration difference between c# and Java I am not aware of?

Comment: In the Java code, in `encoder.encodeToString(message)`, `message` must be replaced with `byteArraySignature`, probably just a copy/paste error as the posted code is not compilable. Aside from that, the verification works on my machine. So check if private and public key are related. That this is not the case seems to me to be the most likely explanation.

Comment: Note that the Java code is not very resilient due to `Charset.defaultCharset()`, `read()` (without loop) and not closed stream. However, this all affects the key import and should not be the cause of your problem, otherwise a corresponding exception should be thrown.